# Inspect WebView on iOS native app

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, remote-debugging, safari-web-inspector

I am able to remote inspect websites on my iPhone's safari by connecting the iPhone to my mac with a lightning cable.

But this does not work with webviews on a native iOS app. In safari (mac) `Develop > My IPhone` shows "No inspectable applications".

How do I remote inspect webview on native apps?